# PyQt5 Multithreading Crashes with No Console Error

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I have a project I am working on for work. Due to the nature of the project I cant share all of the code.

Below is the code of me trying to implement a thread on button click.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtSerialPort
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys, time

class BETA_THREADED(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('rocket_3.ui', self)
        # self.resize(1920, 1080)

        self.thread={}
        self.launchButton.clicked.connect(self.start_worker)
        self.abortButton.clicked.connect(self.stop_worker)

    def start_worker(self):
        print('1')
        self.thread[1] = ThreadClass(parent = None, index = 1)
        self.thread[1].start()
        self.thread[1].any_signal.connect(self.launchSequence)
        self.launchButton.setEnabled(False)

    def stop_worker(self):
        self.thread[1].stop()
        self.launchButton.setEnabled(True)

    def launchSequence(self):
        print('Test')

class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    
    any_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent=None,index=0):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.index=index
        self.is_running = True
    def run(self):
        print('Starting thread...',self.index)
        cnt=0
        while (True):
            cnt+=1
            if cnt==99: cnt=0
            time.sleep(0.01)
            self.any_signal.emit(cnt) 
    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False
        print('Stopping thread...',self.index)
        self.terminate()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = BETA_THREADED()
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The UI file is generated by PyQt Designer, and the buttons are regular push buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Rocket</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="Rocket">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1262</width>
    <height>323</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Rocket</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="statusBar">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>230</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>1011</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>230</x>
      <y>190</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>17</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Carlito</family>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>STATUS</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>-10</x>
      <y>-10</y>
      <width>221</width>
      <height>291</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="flat">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="checkable">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="launchButton">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>30</x>
       <y>60</y>
       <width>161</width>
       <height>101</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Carlito</family>
       <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">background-color: blue;</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>LAUNCH</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="abortButton">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>30</x>
       <y>180</y>
       <width>161</width>
       <height>101</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Carlito</family>
       <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">background-color: red;</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>ABORT</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <tabstops>
  <tabstop>launchButton</tabstop>
  <tabstop>statusBar</tabstop>
  <tabstop>abortButton</tabstop>
 </tabstops>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>launchButton</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>launchButton</receiver>
   <slot>click()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>546</x>
     <y>720</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>546</x>
     <y>720</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>abortButton</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>abortButton</receiver>
   <slot>click()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>630</x>
     <y>910</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>630</x>
     <y>910</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

When I run the file my window opens as expected and then closes on any button click. I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Edit: Corrected the spelling and other error noted, provided the full file for both python and UI. The program still closes on any button click with no error in cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You in Qt Designer incorrectly specify the slot when connecting to a signal

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtSerialPort
from PyQt5 import uic


class Ui_Rocket(object):
    def setupUi(self, Rocket):
        Rocket.setObjectName("Rocket")
        Rocket.resize(1262, 323)
        Rocket.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Rocket)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 220, 1011, 61))
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 190, 111, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Carlito")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setEnabled(True)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, -10, 221, 291))
        self.groupBox.setTitle("")
        self.groupBox.setFlat(False)
        self.groupBox.setCheckable(False)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        
        self.launchButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.launchButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 161, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Carlito")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.launchButton.setFont(font)
        self.launchButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;")
        self.launchButton.setObjectName("launchButton")
        
        self.abortButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.abortButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 180, 161, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Carlito")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.abortButton.setFont(font)
        self.abortButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        self.abortButton.setObjectName("abortButton")
        
        Rocket.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Rocket)
#                                          ???????????????????????         
#        self.launchButton.clicked.connect(self.launchButton.click)
#        self.abortButton.clicked.connect(self.abortButton.click)
        
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Rocket)
        Rocket.setTabOrder(self.launchButton, self.statusBar)
        Rocket.setTabOrder(self.statusBar, self.abortButton)

    def retranslateUi(self, Rocket):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Rocket.setWindowTitle(_translate("Rocket", "Rocket"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Rocket", "STATUS"))
        self.launchButton.setText(_translate("Rocket", "LAUNCH"))
        self.abortButton.setText(_translate("Rocket", "ABORT"))


class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    any_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None, index=0):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.index=index
        self.is_running = True
    def run(self):
        print('Starting thread...',self.index)
        cnt=0
        while (True):
            cnt+=1
            if cnt==99: cnt=0
            time.sleep(0.01)
            self.any_signal.emit(cnt) 
    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False
        print('Stopping thread...',self.index)
        self.terminate()
        

class BETA_THREADED(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Rocket):           # +++ , Ui_Rocket
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)                                       # +++
        
#        self.ui = uic.loadUi('rocket_3.ui', self)
        # self.resize(1920, 1080)

        self.thread = {}
        self.launchButton.clicked.connect(self.start_worker)
        self.abortButton.clicked.connect(self.stop_worker)

    def start_worker(self):
        print('111')
        
        self.thread[1] = ThreadClass(parent = None, index = 1)
        self.thread[1].start()
        self.thread[1].any_signal.connect(self.launchSequence)
        self.launchButton.setEnabled(False)
        
    def stop_worker(self):
        print('222')
        self.thread[1].stop()
        self.launchButton.setEnabled(True)

    def launchSequence(self):
        print('Test')


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = BETA_THREADED()
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]